# How can I show all the complete message of the algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

I’m trying to create a binary tree about the Morse Code.
The program should show all the message but for some reason it only prints the first letter.
What should I do?

```
class Tree: 

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.izq = None
        self.der = None

Arriba = Tree ("    ")

Arriba.izq = Tree("E")

Arriba.der = Tree("T")

Arriba.izq.izq = Tree("I")

Arriba.izq.der = Tree("A")

Arriba.der.izq = Tree("N")

Arriba.der.der = Tree("M")

Arriba.izq.izq.izq = Tree("S")

Arriba.izq.izq.der = Tree("U")

Arriba.izq.der.izq = Tree("R")

Arriba.izq.der.der = Tree("W")

Arriba.der.izq.izq = Tree("D")

Arriba.der.izq.der = Tree("K")

Arriba.der.der.izq = Tree("G")

Arriba.der.der.der = Tree("O")

Arriba.izq.izq.izq.izq = Tree("H")

Arriba.izq.izq.izq.der= Tree("V")

Arriba.izq.izq.der.izq = Tree("F")

Arriba.izq.der.izq.izq = Tree("L")

Arriba.izq.der.der.izq = Tree("P")

Arriba.izq.der.der.der = Tree("J")

Arriba.der.izq.izq.izq = Tree("B")

Arriba.der.izq.izq.der = Tree("X")

Arriba.der.izq.der.izq = Tree("C")

Arriba.der.izq.der.der = Tree("Y")

Arriba.der.der.izq.izq = Tree("Z")

Arriba.der.der.izq.der = Tree("Q")

texto = input("Digite el mensaje cifrado: ")

index = 0
def Cositas (Arriba):
    global index
  
    for i in texto[index]:
        lista  = []
    
        if i == ".":
            index += 1
            Cositas (Arriba.izq)
    
        elif i == "-":
            index +=1
            Cositas (Arriba.der)

        elif i == " ":
            index += 1
            lista.append(Arriba.data)

        elif i == "/" :
            index += 1
            lista.append("---")
      

    for j in lista:
        print("Su mensaje es:")
        print(j,end="")

Cositas(Arriba)
```

Comment: What is `Arriba`? Please share a minimal reproducible example so that we can help

Comment: It is so painful to build the Arriba tree like this. I suggest changing method `__init__` to make it easier. `def __init__(self, data, izq=None, der=None): self.data = data; self.izq=izq; self.der = der`. This way you can build a tree in one line by doing `Arriba = Tree('    ', Tree('E', Tree('I'), Tree('A')), Tree('T', Tree('N'), Tree('M')))`

Comment: Note: When you ask a question on StackOverflow, please don't use `input()` to get the input. Instead, choose a specific message and use it directly in your code. This makes it easier for the people who want to write an answer: they can use the same input as you directly.

Comment: Also: Do not use keyword `global`. You will never ever need it until you are much more proficient with python. 100% of the time that you think you must use `global`, you actually don't need to. It causes more problems than it solves. There is no reason for variable `index` from function `Cositas` to be global.

Comment: It doesn’t change anything of the problem the name Arriba

Comment: Also, I don’t understand your __init__ method. Please explain it better. I’m new at coding and I don’t know so much many things….

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some of the issues:

- When `i` is a space, the process stops: no more calls to `Cositas` are made, and the letters in `texto` that come after that space are not processed.
- When `/` is encountered, a similar problem happens. No more progress is made.
- Every recursive call would print out `"Su mensaje es:"`. It would be more appropriate to not use recursion here, but use loops only
- The `for i in texto[index]` statement will only iterate once, because `texto[index]` is just one character.
- It is bad practice to use a global `index` variable. If you would need to decode multiple messages, you would need to reset it to 0 again. This is not elegant.

I would suggest doing this without recursion. So after you have built the tree `Arriba`, you could continue like this:

```
def cositas (arriba, texto):
    words = []
    for word in texto.split("/"):
        lista = []
        for code in word.split():
            node = arriba
            for ch in code:
                node = node.izq if ch == "." else node.der
            lista.append(node.data)
        words.append("".join(lista))
    return " ".join(words)
        
texto = input("Digite el mensaje cifrado: ")
translation = cositas(Arriba, texto)
print("Su mensaje es:", translation)
```

So if for instance you would input:

> -.-. --- -- . / --.- ..- .. -.-. -.-  / . -. --. .. -. . / .-. --- --- -- / -. . .- .-. .-.. -.-- / ..-. ..- .-.. .-..

...the output would be:

> Su mensaje es: COME QUICK ENGINE ROOM NEARLY FULL

Comment: That’s so thankful. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot for the help